# Variables from `read` in bash script are undefined

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I have this bash script that I use with `i3wm` to toggle between screen modes (external screen, internal screen, all or mirror). The first part of the script grabs the name of the screens. If I copy the following part and runit  in a terminal:

```
#!/bin/bash

xrandr|grep " connected primary"|IFS=" " read INTERNAL_OUTPUT con
xrandr|awk '/ connected/ && !/ primary/'|IFS=" " read EXTERNAL_OUTPUT con
echo internal monitor is $INTERNAL_OUTPUT
echo external monitor is $EXTERNAL_OUTPUT

...
```

I get something like

```
$ ./script.sh
internal monitor is eDPI
external monitor is DPI-1
```

But when I run the actual script, the variables are empty and all I see is

```
$ ./script.sh
internal monitor is 
external monitor is
```

What is the diference when setting the variables inside a script?

Comment: If the `echo` commands are in the same script as the `read` commands they should work, but they won't work outside the script unless you call it with the `.`/`source` command.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The whole thing in inside the script, including the echos, but it doesn't work. The variables are still empty.

Comment: In that case I don't see how it can work from the terminal: the only way I could get it to work is with `xrandr|grep " connected primary"|{ IFS=" " read INTERNAL_OUTPUT con; echo internal monitor is $INTERNAL_OUTPUT; }`, and similarly for the other monitor. This works in both the terminal and a script.

Comment: They don't work for me in a terminal either... Hypothesis: this won't work in `bash`, and your console isn't `bash` (so they work there)(what says `ls -l /proc/$$/exe`?)  but your script requires bash (due to shebang) so uses bash rules and this makes the code fail.

Comment: If you want to set a variable in `bash`, you need something like `INTERNAL_OUTPUT=$(xrandr|grep " connected "|grep -o '^[^ ]*')`. This makes `INTERNAL_OUTPUT` available on subsequent lines in the script, though not on returning to the terminal unless called with `.`. If you want a script to set variables in the current shell without calling `.` you need to code it as a function.

Comment: Oh. It might be because I'm using `zsh` which behaves slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set variables in a pipeline and have the value available outside the pipe.  When running a pipeline each part is run its own subshell, so the `read` command is in its own subshell.  A subshell cannot modify the parent's environment, so the variables you set there are not available to the parent.

To get around this you could do as @AFH says and change the command so only what you want is printed then assign that to a variable in the parent shell.

Alternately, you could restructure the commands so you aren't piping into read.  I'd prefer AFH's approach, but reordering could look like:

```
IFS=" " read INTERNAL_OUTPUT con < <(xrandr|grep " connected primary")
```

where we redirect the input of `read` to be from a process substitution that does the rest of the command, so `read` is still in the parent shell.